# Qt 5.5 not working with MSVS 2015 or 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, qt

I upgraded Qt 5.5 to Qt 5.5 (uninstalled the former first). I was using it with VS2010.

After qt 5.5 installation, it does't pick up the correct compiler. It seems to think I have VS2013 installed which I don't have. [image: This] is what I see in options: The list of compiler is [image: here].

I than even installed VS2015 for the heck of it but it doesn't wwith that either and I get error messsge:

> C1902: Program database manager mismatch; please check your
>   installation

I did created a dummy project in VS2015 and it compiles and run fine but Qt doesn't seem to work with it.

Anyways at least I want to make it work with VS2010 that I already have on my machine but even if I configure a kit with it, it doesn't like it and it shows error:

> error: Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a
>   compiler in the kit options.

But I do set the compiler as in this [image: snapshot].

I am running this on Windows 7 machine.

**Update**

It seems like Qt 5.5 works best with VS2013? I tried to install that but it wouldn't get installed and show [image: this] message which is weird! It requires new version of windows than Win7..really?

**Resolution:**

After receiving and figuring it out, my recommendation is not to use ISO (download the full installation first) installer because one big problem with it is that after it was installed, i couldn't add/remove components to it. When I went into control panel > Install and Qt 5.5 to add VS2010 component, it wouldn't let me and I have to reinstall using web download. That one does allow to add additional components and see what are already installed, much better. See the image bellow of the error when not able to add components.[image]

Comment: Windows Updates installed?

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot from your Qt installer in order to check what Qt5.5 version you have installed ? Qt is compiled for a specific version of VS and it should work only with that specific version.

Comment: "uninstalled the former first" That was completely unnecessary. You can have multiple coexisting Qt versions installed. I usually have about a dozen - it works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems to think I have VS2013 installed which I don't have.

It doesn't "seem to think" anything - you have downloaded a prebuilt, binary version of Qt for Visual Studio 2013. It was your choice.

If there isn't a pre-built version of Qt 5.5 for your version of Visual Studio, you'll need to compile it yourself. If you look at the [release files available](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.0/), you'll see that there *is in fact a version for VS2010*. So download and use that if you don't wish to build your own from sources.

Comment: Yes I figured it out the hard way. I used an ISO file to download which I didn't know would be locked up to VS2013. I tried to add VS2010 but control panel >> installed application wouldn't let me add/updated components. I have now started web based download and selected VS2010 and its half through. This should resolve it when done.

Comment: If that helps, I just wrote an article explaining how to build Qt 5.5.1 with Visual Studio 2015: http://goo.gl/hrvyyP